# How to fix backlight for Dell inspiron on ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS?

Tags: backlight

I work on a Dell Inspiron laptop.
The backlight is not working on Ubuntu. Is there any known issues like this with Ubuntu on Dell machines?

I've tried some solutions such as changing grub like the following sample but still it's not working.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
sudo update-grub
```

Also, I installed xbacklight, but I can only set a value for it once and then I have to restart if I want to decrease the backlight.

Can someone tell me how can I fix it, or what else I can try?

Comment: Are you talking about your screen's backlight or is this about backlit keyboard?

Comment: @terdon screen's backlight.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/424286 this might solve your problem...

Answer (score 2):

[Click Here >> Ubuntu Wiki >> Debugging >> Backlight](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight)

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your comment if i will add the important parts here

Comment: @Hawk-Tech Your link was useful but it still doesn't work properly. I can only change backlight via hotkeys one time. For example if I decrease it I cant increase the backlight. BTW, I've reported the issue. Thanks

Comment: No problem always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Inspiron 1520 running Ubuntu 14.04. For quite a long time I've been looking for a fix on how to control the screen brightness using the Fn+F5/F6 key.

I've tried including some arguments at boot, some packages, nothing worked. Anyway, I stumbled upon [this guide](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/07/install-linux-kernel-3-15-5-ubuntu-14-04/) , update the kernel successfully and, woot!, screen brightness is now available!

PSA: Use this guide on your own. One thing I had to do was downgrade the AMD Drivers to the Ubuntu packages default (fglrx package).